# Galleryview with Zoom in and Zoom out function in android

Tags: android, galleryview

I want a `zoom in` and `zoom out` funcion in `GalleryView` on android.I am trying lot of ways but it does not work. I found another tutorial for `zoom in` and `Zoom out` images in `GalleryView` on android and trying doesn't work 
Can any one help me how to implement this functionality and why doesn't work code on tutorial?

I am trying this tutorial below link:

http://blog.projapps.com/?p=85

like below code :

**MyImageview.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MyImageView extends ImageView {
    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    boolean isDraggable = false;
    boolean isRight = false;
    boolean isLeft = false;

    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    public void setMatrix(Matrix m) {
        matrix.set(m);
    }

    public void setSavedMatrix(Matrix m) {
        savedMatrix.set(m);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (isDraggable) {
            // place pan/zoom codes here
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MyGallery.java**

```
public class MyGallery extends Gallery {
    private PointF m_start = new PointF();
    private MyImageView imageView;

    public MyGallery(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrSet) {
        super(context, attrSet);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        imageView = (MyImageView) getSelectedView();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                m_start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                imageView.isDraggable = true;
                if (imageView.getScaleType() != ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX) {
                    imageView.setMatrix(imageView.getImageMatrix());
                    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if ((event.getX() - m_start.x < 0 && imageView.isRight) ||
                    (event.getX() - m_start.x > 0 && imageView.isLeft))
                    imageView.isDraggable = false;
                break;
        }
        if (!imageView.isDraggable) {
            onTouchEvent(event);
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

and i am loading image adapter class like below code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImageIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            MyImageView i = new MyImageView(mContext);
            i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            return i;            
        }

        private Context mContext;

    }
```

and load image adapter in my gallery class like below code:

```
    g = (MyGallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    g.setSpacing(60);
    g.setUnselectedAlpha(1);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

this code load images sucessfully but, does not work zoom functionality!

Comment: Hey ! Welcome to SO. Great going!Consider sharing with us some code what you have written or at what point you failed to achieve it. Everyone is here to help you. Happy Coding :)

Comment: @Abhilasha i am update my question can u help me?